# Userspace process preempts kernel thread?

Tags: c, linux

Currently I am reading "Understanding the Linux kernel, 3rd edition" and on p.22 I can read:

> In the simplest case, the CPU executes a kernel control path sequentially from the
>   first instruction to the last. When one of the following events occurs, however, the
>   CPU interleaves the kernel control paths:
>
> - A process executing in User Mode invokes a system call, and the corresponding
>     kernel control path verifies that the request cannot be satisfied immediately; it
>     then invokes the scheduler to select a new process to run. As a result, a process
>     switch occurs. The first kernel control path is left unfinished, and the CPU
>     resumes the execution of some other kernel control path. In this case, the two
>     control paths are executed on behalf of two different processes.

The kernel control path can be interrupted from a user space process doing a system call?
I thought the priority was pretty much:

- interrupts
- kernel threads
- user space processes

I have checked the errata and could not find anything about this.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for editing. This is new stuff for me.

Comment: NP: there is help available while you're typing a question, but it takes a little experience to do it automatically.  After you've been here a few years (actually, a month or so is probably sufficient), you'll be formatting it without thinking too hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about the priority list, but what (I think) the book is trying to say is:

- When a (user) process makes a system call, the kernel starts executing on its behalf.
- If the system call can be completed (the kernel control path does not run into a roadblock), then it will usually return direct to the calling process - think `getpid()` function call.
- On the other hand, if the system call cannot be completed (for example, because the disk system must read a block into the kernel buffer pool before its data can be returned to the calling process), then the scheduler is used to select a new process to run - preempting the (kernel thread of control that was running on behalf of the) user process.
- In due course, the original system call will be able to continue, and the original (kernel thread of control that was running on behalf of the) user process will be able to continue and eventually complete, returning control to the user space process running in user space and not in the kernel.

So "No": it is not the case that the 'kernel path can be interrupted from a user space process doing a system call'.

The kernel path can be interrupted while it is executing a system call on behalf of a user space process because: an interrupt occurs, or the kernel path must wait for a resource to become available, or ...

Comment: Good answer.Even though I am not a fluent english speaker/reader I still think they could have done a better job describing this situation. Maybe hire you as a cowriter? :)

Comment: Perhaps they'll notice this and fix it in the 4th Edition?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I was curious about how the hardware switches the mode when doing a context switch. For e.g. a process calls fread(). This causes an interrupt which switches the CPU from user mode to kernel mode. But the disk drive is busy. Hence the scheduler decides to run a new process. However this process might be in user mode. How does the kernel change the CPU from kernel mode to user mode again? Interrupts, perhaps?
P.S: I am referring the same book and have similar doubts. Please let me know if my above understanding is wrong.

Comment: @ChethanRavindranath: I've not read the book in question, so I can't guarantee that what I say will mesh with what they say.  The switch from user space to kernel space is done with a hardware instruction that saves enough of the original context (program counter (P), stack pointer (SP), maybe but probably not some other registers), and then runs the kernel mode code that finishes saving the context (other registers) before getting on with appropriate kernel mode activity.  [...continued...]

Comment: [...continuation...] Switching back to user mode from kernel mode is rather the reverse; recover the saved registers and then use the appropriate hardware instruction to reinstate the PC and SP back to where the user code left off.  This is stuff that happens every time a system call is made, or an interrupt occurs and has to affect the user-space process.  It also usually involves some small snippets of assembler code; it is not something that can be written in C (for example) on most machines.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler! I was just curious how the kernel switches the hardware from user mode to kernel mode. Does it raise an interrupt on itself for a process context switch or does it just execute an instruction that switches the CPU from kernel mode to user mode etc. I am also guessing its implementation specific but just curious if there is an standard way of doing it.

Comment: @ChethanRavindranath: It varies with CPU type.  There's usually (always?) an instruction to do the job, but it is sufficiently long since I looked at the details that I've no idea what the instructions are called in any current CPU architecture (either because I never knew or because I've forgotten).  The MC68000 series machines had a TRAP instruction, for example.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler. I ll see if I can find anything on the web and post it here if I find anything!